# Protractor "by.css()" vs "$()" Dollar Sign vs "$$()" 'Bling Bling'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I don't really understand what the $ and $$ commands are for. I thought they are just a replacement for 'by.css' but why the $$?

```
<element id = "eId"></element>
```

I thought, that given the above, these would be equivalent:

```
element(by.css('#eId'));
```

and

```
element($('#eId'));
```

However, the first one works and the second doesn't. Why, what's the difference between the three?

The [docs](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=build$) are of little help. They seem to imply that "$" is for chaining only, e.g. `element(by.css('#eId')).element($('#childId'));` or "Select the first element, and then select the second element within the first element.' However, I have seen examples with $ being used to select the first element.

Anyway, that's a lot of text for "What are the differences between the three (by.css, $, and $$)?"

Comment: I viewed this because it had "bling bling" in the title lol :)

Comment: Just keepin it gangsta yo. Anyway, apparently 'bling bling' is an actual nickname for the '$$' shortcut, from reading the other posts here. Also, if I understand correctly, you can't search posts/google by symbols such as '$' or '#', etc, so I included the nickname in the name.

Comment: I get you. It's all good in the 'hood. :D

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`$`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$) and [`$$`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$) are just convenient shortcuts.

`$("selector")` is an alternative for `element(by.css("selector"))`.

`$$("selector")` is an alternative for `element.all(by.css("selector"))`.

---

FYI, quote from the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.js):

```
ElementFinder.prototype.$ = function(selector) {
  return this.element(webdriver.By.css(selector));
};

ElementArrayFinder.prototype.$$ = function(selector) {
  return this.all(webdriver.By.css(selector));
};
```

And the [actual commit](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/a2cd6c8baf242a81c4efea1f55249d597de95329) that initially made it happen.

Comment: Clear and concise, thanks. Got both $ and $$ to work. I guess I was confusing myself over the basics. I was doing element.$() instead of just $(). Thanks. Lol, I feel like we are going to build a database of protractor basics here if I keep failing at writing scripts.