# Adding custom locator shortcuts in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors, protractor

In Protractor, there are [`$` and `$$` convenient shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881583/protractor-by-css-vs-dollar-sign-vs-bling-bling) for CSS selectors:

```
$(".myclass")  // means: element(by.css(".myclass"))
$$(".myclass")  // means: element.all(by.css(".myclass"))
```

Is it possible to *introduce custom shortcuts* for other locators?

---

To be more specific, what if we want to have a `$r` and `$$r` shortcuts for "by repeater" calls. To be able to write:

```
$r("item in items")  
$$r("item in items")
```

instead of:

```
element(by.repeater("item in items"))
element.all(by.repeater("item in items"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a shortcut, add the custom locator on the global namespace and on the prototype of `ElementFinder` and `ElementArrayFinder`:

```
global.$r = function(selector) {
  return protractor.element(protractor.by.repeater(selector));
};

global.$$r = function(selector) {
  return protractor.element.all(protractor.by.repeater(selector));
};

ElementFinder.prototype.$$r = function(selector) {
  return this.all(protractor.by.repeater(selector));
};

ElementFinder.prototype.$r = function(selector) {
  return this.element(protractor.by.repeater(selector));
};

ElementArrayFinder.prototype.$$r = function(selector) {
  return this.all(protractor.by.repeater(selector));
};
```

Usage:

```
$r("item in items")
$$r("item in items")
$("#id").$r("item in items")
$("#id").$$r("item in items")
```

Comment: I couldn't implement this in my project. I tried few ways. Do you mind sharing your code, I want to understand how did you add custom locators to global namespace? 
I always got this error: "$x is not a function". Tried adding element(by.xpath)